# How to read spectral data from this FITS file?

Tags: specutils

I am a new user to SpecUtils and I am simply attempting to read in spectral data from a FITS file and plot the spectrum, just like on the first page of [SpecUtils](https://specutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

My code is identical to the first page of SpecUtils and is as follows:

```
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy import units as u
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from astropy.visualization import quantity_support
quantity_support()  # for getting units on the axes below  

f = fits.open('GIRAF.2021-02-14T01:00:34.723.fits')  
# The spectrum is in the second HDU of this file.
specdata = f[0].data 
f.close() 

from specutils import Spectrum1D
lamb = 10**specdata['loglam'] * u.AA 
flux = specdata['flux'] * 10**-17 * u.Unit('erg cm-2 s-1 AA-1') 
spec = Spectrum1D(spectral_axis=lamb, flux=flux)
```

However, it seems `loglam` and `flux` are no acceptablr identifiers from this file

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [22], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 from specutils import Spectrum1D
----> 2 lamb = 10**specdata['loglam'] * u.AA 
      3 flux = specdata['flux'] * 10**-17 * u.Unit('erg cm-2 s-1 AA-1') 
      4 spec = Spectrum1D(spectral_axis=lamb, flux=flux)

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Does anyone have any advice on how I can figure out what the headers are in my file, how to read them in, and then ultimately plot the spectral data? Here is the link to the FITS file: [link](https://sendgb.com/Of8Ls21eYGa)

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert the variable `specdata` to numpy before doing the operations.

Replace

> ```
> specdata = f[0].data
> ```

to

> ```
> specdata = np.array(f[0].data)
> ```